# Semaphore in os

Tags: operating-system

A semaphore is needed to effectively ensure that only one student (out of a class of three students) has access to the examination attendance at a time. When the 1st student is doing ‘write name’, 2nd student is doing ‘write book no’ and the 3rd student is doing ‘sign attendance’.